# Open Source Security Frameworks for .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, security

Are there any security frameworks that are open source for ASP.NET web forms or MVC?  I'm looking for something to authenticate users, and authorization capabilities if possible.  Just to note, I am NOT interested in the Membership API, but am looking for a framework that has similar capabilities.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if you told us what you want? The membership provider is a bit bloated and do a lot of things. Asking for something similar makes your question very broad. It's quite easy to customize the ASP.NET authentication process. I've also created a membership provider with better extension points.

Comment: Authenticating users and their roles, and authorizing them if possible.

Comment: What's wrong with the membership provider? (need to understand why it doesn't work to be able to provide an alternative)

Comment: @jgauffin I'm researching alternatives at the moment.  However, while it works well, it often doesn't fit several application level security models.

Comment: `IIPrincipal` and `IIdentity` which the .NET security model (CAS and not claims) is based on user roles. MembershipProvider just load up those users and roles for you. If roles doesn't work for you, you have to switch to some framework that uses claims based security.

Comment: @jgauffin Well that's all what a part of what I'm looking into.  However, Membership is not the only utility to use IPrincipal and IIdentity; you can implement your own using these objects, and I'm sure there are other frameworks others have built.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I'd post my open source authentication framework. You didn't say too much about your use case, so I'm not sure how well of a fit it'd be, but I'm sure it's a good starting point since it's BSD licensed.

Anyway, my authentication framework is called FSCAuth. It's located at [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/earlz/fscauth) and BSD licensed.

Basically, it's goal is to stay out of your way and be significantly simpler to implement than ASP.Net's Membership API.

Some things it has going for it:

1. A "stateless" authentication system. This means no database tables required to keep track of logged in users, and therefore trivial to scale to multiple servers.
2. Simple, yet fine grained authorization. Everything is specified in code, and without any magic attributes.
3. Extremely secure out of the box. Out of the box it uses SHA256 hashing with salt. It's also trivial to configure for [BCrypt support](http://lastyearswishes.com/blog/view/4e2c779d4aa5d80931d7cb94)
4. No messing with hashes or cookies. I try to make it as difficult as possible for your to make your application insecure, this includes handling all of the hashes and cookies.
5. HTTP Basic Auth out of the box, and works the same way as cookie authentication
6. Trivial to put into an existing database. It works by using an interface called a `UserStore`. Examples: [MongoDB UserStore](http://lastyearswishes.com/blog/view/4db256c04aa5d8071307ef7a), [SQL Server UserStore](http://lastyearswishes.com/blog/view/4df536514aa5d847bb0e89ad)
7. Supports .Net 2.0+ and runs on Mono and in Medium-trust

It also has some limitations to it.

1. Windows/domain authentication will never be implemented.
2. It only has the notion of users and groups. There isn't anything built in for user-group-role or anything like that.
3. It has some problems with IIS 6 (can't protect static pages and requires a hellish amount of configuration)
4. It's configuration doesn't use the Web.Config (which I like, but some people don't)

Comment: "runs in Medium-Trust" and "it has some problems with IIS 6" means that FSCAuth has a web UI to administer users/groups?

Comment: @BrianMains no, sadly not. It may come out with a simplistic web UI in the future, but for right now, no. "bootstrapping" configuration is sadly where it lacks right now. You basically have to make a special page or something that will add your administrative users

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind is [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) but I don't know if it can suit your needs.

Comment: I'm researching security frameworks where the data is kept in-house, but that is good to know.  I forgot about that one.  Thanks.